# Why is my large file when extracted is of very less size on google colab?

Tags: python, bash, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I am using the 'Dogs vs. Cats Redux: Kernels Edition' dataset from kaggle for a deep learning model.

```py
import os
from getpass import getpass
user = getpass('Kaggle Username: ')
key = getpass('Kaggle API key: ')

if '.kaggle' not in os.listdir('/root'):
    !mkdir ~/.kaggle
!touch /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!chmod 666 /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json
with open('/root/.kaggle/kaggle.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write('{"username":"%s","key":"%s"}' % (user, key))


!kaggle competitions download -c dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition
```

I have downloaded it in my colab notebook environment, the total dataset size(test+train) is of approximately greater than 800mbs.

```sh
ls -sh
    112K sample_submission.csv  272M test.zip  544M train.zip
```

However, when I extract the train and test zip, why is the size of the extracted file so less?

```sh
unzip test.zip && unzip train.zip
ls -sh
    total 816M
    112K sample_submission.csv  272M test.zip  544M train.zip
    276K test           752K train
```

**The unzip happens without the quiet mode so I can see the files are getting extracted one by one**

***Also I can see the images inside the `test` folder which are completely accessible through the side directory***

I thought this was some size display bug by the `ls` command and the files are really extracted, but when running the training code, it throws error related to images not found.

I unzipped some files by uploading a small dataset locally and they are working fine, so `unzip` is working fine too, same is the case with 7z and python unzipping.

Any approach towards the problem or alternate solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the size of the directory instead of the size of its contents.

Try checking the size with `du` instead.

Comment: Ok, But why is the size of directory different than the size of its contents, is the size of directory not equal to the size of content it holds?

Comment: Basically what you're looking at is a special file containing metadata describing the directory contents. That is, it's a list of the filenames in the directory (simplified).